# How to start Firefox/Chrome drivers with turned off HTML5 field validation

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I use Firefox/Chrome Webdriver drivers for testing my web app. This app has HTML5 field validation. When my test doesn't fill in text field with type `"email"` and submits form then FirefoxDriver sets focus to the field (without showing HTML5 field validation error) instead of sending POST request to server side.

Do Firefox/Chrome drivers have profile settings/preferences that will turn off HTML5 field validation?

Comment: I'm not clear what's asked here, problem-solving or asking for a way to set `HTML5 field validation` in browsers' profile? Or just a way to turn off `HTML5 field validation`?

Comment: @user1177636 If it's possible to start a browser with turned off HTML5 field validation it would be a good solution.

Comment: @user1177636 If I could, I wouldn't ask a question ;)

Comment: Then what language are you using? Try use `IJavaScriptExecutor` to remove it. "Turn off" and "remove element's attribute" are clearly two different questions.

Comment: @user1177636 I use Ruby but I think it doesn't matter much as it's easy to translate from Java/whatever if you know a name of profile setting/preference/swicth

Comment: Try something like `driver.execute_script("document.getElementByID('email_input').setAttribute('type', 'text')")`.

Comment: @user1177636 I thought about removing that attribute using Javascript but it looks too hacky since there is more than one field with HTML5 validation. A better solution would be to start a browser with turned off field validation

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a workaround for it by using JS script from http://novalidate.com/
Just make sure to run this script:

```
    for(var f=document.forms,i=f.length;i--;)f[i].setAttribute("novalidate",i)
```

any time a new page / form is loaded.